SF Children's book about a girl from outer space not understanding what fun was
Around 1969 I read a book that I only remember vaguely. There was a scene where a girl from another planet is talking to an Earth boy about her age, and he mentions having fun, and she doesn't understand what he means. Apparently, on her planet people don't have fun. That's all I remember of the story.
I read it in school. It was written for perhaps fifth graders, so I would assume that the characters were about ten years old. Can't remember if it was a standalone story or part of an anthology or textbook or something. I vaguely remember that there was an illustration of the boy and girl against a dark background in the stereotypical sci-fi style of the era.
